# Java change linux fedora + KDE wallpapers

Tags: java, linux, fedora, desktop, kde-plasma

I want to change user's wallpapers using java. Im planning to use this only on KDE, not Gnome or something like that. I dont want to use something that will execute terminal script on other language. By the way, i googled if KDE stores wallpapers somewhere in the envoriment/files, but theres no such folders/env variables (i used grep to check)

Comment: A quick search on `GitHub` shows a [`Python` implementation](https://github.com/himanshuxd/RandomWallpaperKDE). Perhaps it can be adapted to your needs? More searching will probably reveal alternatives as well.

Comment: Yeah, thanks! Should be enough